# SQL Update statement (what's wrong?)

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

What's wrong with my following sql statement? (oledb) I get a 'Syntax error in UPDATE statement.'

`"UPDATE LogIn SET Username='" + EditUsernameTextBox.Text + "', Password='" + EditPasswordTextBox.Text + "' WHERE (ID =" + IDTextBox.Text + ")";`